# How can I configure iCloud mail in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: icloud, email

i just downloaded Thunderbird from Mozilla because it's the only program I can use to access my hosting email addresses in a easy way, but when I try to add my iCloud account, I get an error.

Here's how I'm trying to configure it (sorry for the Spanish).

[image: Screenshot of Thunderbird's mail settings pane]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These settings work for me, see also https://support.apple.com/HT202304.

Incoming

- Protocol: IMAP
- Server: imap.mail.me.com
- Port: 993
- SSL: SSL/TLS
- Authentication: Normal password

Outgoing

- Protocol: SMTP
- Server: smtp.mail.me.com
- Port: 587
- SSL: STARTTLS
- Authentication: Normal password

Username for both should just be your actual username "karlo_lopez", not your whole email address.

[image: Demonstration of correct iCloud settings for Thunderbird]

**VERY IMPORTANT NOTE:**
If your Apple ID is protected with [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915), then you need to [setup an app-specific password](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204397) within your Apple ID account. Enter that password instead of your normal iCloud password when setting up the email address into Thunderbird.

Comment: Didn't work for me until I save settings and change again username removing the domain.

Comment: Worked for me too after all this time. I also notice that the icloud settings are already available if you start off with an icloud email account. I did have to set up an app-specific password. Don’t you just love it when it all comes together?