# Thunderbird stopped working with iCloud email

Tags: icloud, email, macos, authentication

I had Thunderbird configured with an iCloud (me) email account and it worked fine until about two weeks ago. When I tried to send a message, it asked me for the server password. When I entered it, I got a message saying the login or password was wrong. I also had this same problem on another machine with another account. I was able to add and use a Gmail account without any problems.

My setting are:
Incoming

```
Protocol: IMAP
Server: imap.mail.me.com
Port: 993
SSL: SSL/TLS
Authentication: Normal password
```

Outgoing

```
Protocol: SMTP
Server: smtp.mail.me.com
Port: 587
SSL: STARTTLS
Authentication: Normal password
```

I got the settings from [How can I configure iCloud mail in Mozilla Thunderbird?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141822/how-can-i-configure-icloud-mail-in-mozilla-thunderbird)

I am able to login to both iCloud accounts through a browser.

Comment: you have an old @me.com mail right ?

Comment: One of the machines is me.com and the other is icloud.com

Answer (score 3):

[Starting June 15, 2017](http://www.macworld.com/article/3197439/security/apples-new-icloud-security-requirements-how-it-affects-you-and-the-software-you-use.html), Apple requires [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/HT204915) on all iCloud accounts that access their accounts non-natively. Apple’s [third-party email client setup instructions](https://support.apple.com/HT202304) have since been updated accordingly.

Native iCloud access is limited to **System Preferences** on macOS, the **Settings** app on iOS, and **iCloud for Windows**. All other apps, including Thunderbird and Outlook, require an [app-specific password](https://support.apple.com/HT204397).

To enable two-factor authentication:

- On an iOS device open **Settings** → **Password & Security** and tap `Turn On Two-Factor Authentication`.
- On your Mac open **** → **System Preferences** → **iCloud** → **Account Details** → **Security** and click `Turn On Two-Factor Authentication…`.

Then, login at https://id.apple.com/ and under **Security** → **App-Specific Passwords**, click `Generate Password…`. Enter *that* password into Thunderbird.

This was done to keep third-party apps from getting access to your iCloud password, thus reducing the likelihood of iCloud account breaches.